# Object not defined in Loop

Tags: julia

I create an object and then try to use it in a loop

```
a = 0
for i in 1:2
        a += 1
end
```

However, this results in the following error:

```
UndefVarError: a not defined
```

Have I forgotten how loops work or what is going wrong?

Comment: What Julia version are you on? Under Julia 1.5 this will work if you run this code in REPL or within a local scope (e.g. within a function).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is that your `a` is a global variable and in Julia versions between 1.0 and 1.4.2 the local scoping for variables within loops was introduced. More precisely if you do not explicitly say you want to mutate a global variable (`global a += 1`) a new variable within a local scope is introduced.

The best thing to do is to upgrade to Julia 1.5. Julia 1.5 has introduced back [soft scoping in the REPL](https://julialang.org/blog/2020/08/julia-1.5-highlights/#the_return_of_soft_scope_in_the_repl).

If you need to stick with the current Julia version you could use `global` keyword or place your code in a function or use Jupyter notebook instead (that has soft scoping)  or surround your code around `let`...`end` block such as:

```
 let
    a = 0
    for i in 1:2
        a += 1
    end
    a
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. Yes, I am in 1.3.1. I would so like to really fall in love with `Julia` but again and again I come across problems like 'yeah, that was changed in version x, so it works differently now.' I really hope, the language will get into a stable state sometime.

Comment: Honestly, more people was also pissed off with this situation and now the depreciation warning have been turned off so people cannot change the API all the time. Hence you can expect the language to stabilize from now on.